# How do you delete a file with gitPython

Tags: gitpython

How do you delete a file with gitPython?

```
   repo.delete([file_to_delete])
```

says that there is no delete method.

Answer (score 5):

The problem I had was that I was deleting the file from the repository but not the working tree.  The answer is to do the following:

```
repo.index.remove([file_to_delete],working_tree = True)
```

Without the working_tree argument the file is left in the working tree even though it is not in the repository.